# How can I print an error message if 5 or more characters are entered

Tags: c, string, validation, input, error-handling

I have tried making the array 5 characters long so I can check if the last position has changed but then the program takes in the enter key as a fifth character input and I can't figure out how to fix that either.

```
char input[4];

printf("Please enter your 4 digit pin: ");
scanf(" %s", &input);
```

Comment: `scanf(" %4s" ...` will consume only 4 characters. (It will write up to 5, including the terminating null.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
    #include <string.h>
    char input[20];
    printf("Please enter your 4 digit pin: "); scanf(" %s", &input);

    if ( strlen(input) > 4 ) printf("Entered more than 4 characters")
```

Comment: Might crash with an input such as `0123456789+0123456789-0123456789`

Comment: I think this is exactly what I was looking for. Working perfectly so far. Thanks.

Comment: Basile Starynkevitch you might be right, but it is the classic way to do it. Your suggestion is more robust way to do it surely as long as it is a serious project.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that there are still ways for the program to malfunction this way but it's just for a school assignment where we haven't really learned anything yet but our lecturer told us we need to implement "appropriate input validation" so Im just trying to cover some basic stuff in this case. Thanks again, hasnt caused any problems as of yet :D

Comment: This is a mistake.  You should *never* use `"%s"` without a width specifier.  It is as bad as using `gets`

Answer (score 2):

A 4 digit pin takes *five* characters a least, because of the terminating null byte.

You could try

```
char input[8];
memset (input, 0, sizeof(input));
printf("Please enter your 4 digit pin:\n");
if (fgets (input, sizeof(input), stdin)) {
  /// handle input
}
else {
   fprintf(stderr, "fgets failure\n");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

For robustness, the `input` is cleared with `memset`. If you compile with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), be sure to enable all warnings and debug info (so use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Read also the documentation of your [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)) and of course of your [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler).

However, in 2020, [UTF-8 is everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/), so things are more complex. My French [AZERTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY) keyboard could input the `€` sign (on Linux). You might want to use [GNU libunistring](https://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/).

Remember to read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/), [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c), and be aware that standard functions (like `fgets` or `scanf`) can fail. See [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) for more.

Comment: Im not too sure how this is supposed to work I've never seen a good portion of it. I tried just running that and the program just ends no matter what I input.

Comment: Did you try to use a debugger?

Comment: Im not even totally sure what that means lol. Not been programming for very long and c even less.

Comment: A debugger is a program like GDB, mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Ah, I don't have anything of the sort. ill have a look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can limit the amount of data that scanf will consume by putting a field width on the conversion specifier.  eg: `" %4s"`

```
char input[5];
if( scanf(" %4s", input) == 1 ) { ...
```

Note that the field width should be one less than the size of the buffer, since scanf will write one more character (the null byte) than it consumes.

If you want to verify that there is no more data after the pin, or that the next character is a newline or some other delimiter, do another read.  I consider that to be out of the scope of this question, as the key here is limiting the amount of data your initial scanf reads.

On a side note: it's probably easier to *not* use scanf for this.  If you want exactly 4 characters, use `fgetc` in a loop.  There are fewer edge cases to worry about, and the code will likely be more comprehensible.

Comment: I have already fiddled with %4s a lot but there have been so many bugs appearing when I do. Ill have a look into fgetc though. Thanks!